# How can i import a old .net4.8 vb project to a new.net6 project

Tags: .net, vb.net, upgrade

Using VS 2019, If I start a new directory for a vb.net6 project can I just go to project > add an existing item and will file's be copied to my new folder, and will mean I am all set? of is it best t start from new and copy code from the previous project?

Is there a better way so I don't have to redo everything I have done?  Is it worth the trouble to start now instead of putting it off to go to .net 6 or would .net5 be better?

Comment: .Net 6 (also .Net 5) is from the .Net Core line, whereas .Net 4.8 is from the .Net Framework line. The two are sufficiently different that you're probably best off starting over and copying code where possible. If you are using any 3rd party Libs/Controls you need to check if there are .Net Core compatible versions available before you even begin.

Comment: There some paths for straight conversion from .net framework to .net core.  It's up to you really though how best to do it.  Bit of documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/